# IBAction to display next object of array

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to do something I thought was going to be very simple but I can't figure it out. I'm filling an array with objects like this in `TableViewController`:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    detailController.textArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Text1", @"Text2", @"Text3", @"Text4", @"Text5", nil];
}
```

Then in the `DetailController` I added this action to make the label display the next object of the textArray:

```
- (IBAction)nexTextButtonPressed:(id)sender {
int i = 0;
if (i<[textArray count])
    i++;
    textLabel.text = [textArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

I connected the button in ib to the action with option Touch Down (tried some of the others too). Something isn't working, the button jumps to the second object of the array but then it doesn't work any more. What could be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int i = 0; is initialized inside the method, it will always be reinitialized to zero on every call which will not let you move forward from second object

Comment: Thanks! a little too early in the morning to make codes i think:/

Answer (score 0):

Well every time you hit the button i is getting reset to 0 so when it hits the `if statement` yes it goes into the statement as the condition is correct, but then you are incrementing i by 1 so i becomes 1 then you retrieve the array index 1 every time. You aren't actually doing anything else. No loop to print through the array or anything.